# How to delete row in JTable based on Combo selection

Tags: java, sql, runtime-error

I need to delete rows in a JTable based on whether a user selects 'yes' or 'no'. The problem that I have now is that I get an error saying 'check the right syntax near ".

```
if(searchCombo_Job.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Question ID")){
    String search = searchTxt_Job.getText();
    int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "This will delete all rows selected. Proceed?", "Confirm Delete", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        dlt = "DELETE from job where question_id = " + search + "' ";                        
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(dlt);
        //pst.setString(1, search);
        ((DefaultTableModel)jobCategoryTable.getModel()).removeRow(jobCategoryTable.getSelectedRow());
        pst.execute();
    }
    else {
        fillTableJobCategory();
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to enclose your `search` value in single quotes, but you don't have a leading quote for it. When asking SO questions, make sure you tell when you get the message, in addition to the entire message; I'm assuming this one shows up when you run it, as an error from parsing the SQL statement prior to running it.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Answer (score 0):

If job.question_id is a string field, use

```
dlt = "DELETE from job where question_id = '" + search.trim() + "' ";
```

I would use query parameters to avoid this error. The line then would be

```
dlt = "DELETE from job where question_id = ?";
```

Parameters are also a prevention for SQL injection attacks.